# how to encode high bit rate video

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-2.3-gingerbread

I am facing a problem while playing streamed high bitrate video on gingerbread. First of all i wanted to encode that video. I am using Any video converter. My video format is MP4, i wanted to know, what setting i should do to encode the video.

Here is the specification of the video

```
Format:-MP4V
FrameSize-320x240
Frames/sec:- 20fps.
```

To work this video on Android gingerbread, which codec i should use,

```
xvid
mpeg4
x264
```

and what bitrate,framerate i should use.
Please help.